# Rotation of a cropped portion of a raster map

Tags: gdal, leaflet, affine-transformation, rotate, world-file

We create printed maps from a GeoTIFF file projected in LCC, which is a common projection for aviation maps. Part of our process includes customization of the raster image by selecting a region and adding other design elements. The final part of the process allows for the customer to select desired airports on the map via a custom leaflet application showing all the airports via a GeoJSON file.

We would like to have the tiles map image the customer sees in the Leaflet application be similar to the way the printed map will appear to the customer. This means they will stay in LCC and we crop and raster tile the actual artwork for use in leaflet. We have this all worked out just fine with tiling the resulting image and using leaflet and proj4leaflet. The issue we have is sometimes would like to rotate the crop so that the raster image does not end up aligning with the LCC projection.

Shown here is a copy of my main image where you can see the inside image which will make up our final printed artwork. The inlayed image aligns with the original image, but the cropped area is rotated about 13 degrees.

[image: Map]

I would like to output inset cropped image, rotated so that it appears as it would appear hanging on the wall. This would involve rotating the image about 13 degrees.

[image: rotated image]

If it were not rotated, we easily calculate a new TFW and include the northing and easting components by calculating the pixel size and the amount of the crop. This all works out perfectly.

However, with it being rotated, we need to add the rotation components to the TFW file and I have been unsuccessful in trying to figure that out.

The end results should be a map which appears to be a cropped version of the main map, projected in LCC, but rotated 13 degrees so that it appears online as it would appear hanging on the wall.

**Things I've Tried**

I've studied the page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file and worked out that I need to do some trig on the pixel values.

The other completely unknown is if Leaflet and proj4leaflet can even handle these translations? Answer -- YES, I think I can use the Leaflet.Transformation function for this once I figure out the transformation to use for the rotation.

**Update**

Here is a concrete example of what I am trying to do along with the files.

The projection of these are
`'+proj=lcc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=45 +lat_2=33 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'`

Here is a portion of the the map I'm working with along with the accompanying [pgw](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh6qv6vws7mldz7/top-left-corner.pgw?dl=1) file.

[image: corner image]

Here is that same image rotated 45 degrees (around the center of the image)

[image: corner image rotated]

What should the corresponding world file be for the rotated 45 image and how do you calculate each field in that file.

Comment: GIS SE works better if you explain what you have attempted, rather than just stating that you were unsuccessful.

Comment: @Vince I will work on updating the question as to what I have tried, which is mainly just trying to calculate the new values for the TFW file.

Comment: Is your raster map layer image overlay or tiled layer?

Comment: It is a tiled layer.

Comment: I think I really just need to work out the affine transformation to turn the pixel coordinates into the coordinates of the underlying coordinate system since when you rotate things it won’t be aligned on the same grid anymore. I don’t quite understand how to calculate those rotation values to be placed in the world file. I’ve read about it but don’t understand if the meters per pixel need to change or not? I know it’ll require some trig.

Comment: As you have found out you have a problem, since you have tiled raster layer and Leaflet, unlike OpenLayers, does not offer on-the-fly reprojection od tiled raster layers. One possible primitive way to solve this would be to rotate layer `div` element. I played a bit with this, but there are several problems to be solved: size of the map, position of controls, map panning, resizing and zooming ... It could be done, but would require quite some work. Correct solution would be to reproject map before tiling to some suitable  UTM projection.

Comment: The other solution would be to simply never rotate the slice I take from the LCC projection. I just want it to appear on the screen as it would hang on the wall and not a rotated cut out from the main image.

Comment: @TomazicM - I don't need on the fly reprojection. I tile the artwork in raster form and then use proj4Leaflet to handle the LCC CRS. This all works just fine as long as my cropped map aligns with the LCC CRS grid (ie: no affine transformation). 

I am thinking that I could get this to work if I could work out the transformation required, because I could then just plug in this transformation into the Leaflet Transform function. I don't reproject the artwork in WGS85 because I want it to maintain its flat appearance.

Comment: There are 3 coordinate systems at play here. The raster coordinate (0,0 top left), the LCC coordinate (0,0 is in meters in Kansas) and then Lat/Long in Leaflet.

I need to come up with the function which for a given pixel coordinate (raster) it produces the correct coordinate in the LCC projection. When the two grids are aligned, it is easy because it is just the pixel width and height (in meters) multiplied by the the pixel rows and columns added to the starting position (0,0 in raster)... However, once you rotate things, you need to transform those values and this is where I am lost.

Comment: Your theory would be OK if Leaflet would work with canvas, but it works with grid of `<img>` elements. You can't control view pixel position here. And again, Leaflet does no pixel transformation/reprojection. Any transform or proj4 projection is used only so that displayed pixels can be correctly mapped to lat,lng coordinates and vice versa. Whatever the original tile looks like, so it will be displayed in Leaflet. Only image layer can be transformed/rotated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118524/discussion-between-jr-and-tomazicm).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no fan of discussions and chats.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest leveraging [Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated) - it's able to display raster images given three control corners, as shown in its [demo](https://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/demo.html):

[image: leaflet imageoverlay rotated demo]

The control corners are trivially calculated from a worldfile: one of them is the coordinate of the top-left pixel (lines 5 and 6 of a worldfile) - other is the top-left plus (width in pixels) times the width scale-skew (lines 1 and 2) and the third one is top-left plus (height in pixels) times the height scale-skew (lines 3 and 4).

Comment: I don’t think this would work since my map isn’t an overlay, but a tiled layer.